# javascript giving wrong data at the start of the page's lifetime

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
function ttt(element){
    console.log(element.scrollHeight);
}


ttt($('#testdiv')[0]); // this gives 700

setTimeout(function(){
    ttt($('#testdiv')[0]);  //this gives 2812
}, 600);
```

Can anyone explain this? For it happens on every single page with every script i use, and i don't know why.

But for some reason i have to ask javascript to wait at least 500 milliseconds, before it'll give the correct information.
And it's just not scrollHeight it's everything i have tried.

And if it helps i load in the scripts at the bottom of my html page, and i have all of it in a jquery `$(document).ready` function.

Comment: it could be an image taking up more space (height) but it's not loaded at the time you check the first time

Comment: does this include objects that i load in using ajax?

Comment: of course! Think about it... what you do is, you load stuff and update the DOM with new loaded stuff which will take up space .. depending on the CSS, it will not take up space if you set it all to `display: none;` but then also it will not be visible to anyone .. so what you could do is, when ever an ajax call finishes and content is loaded check again for the height

Comment: That sound reasonable i'll try it. Also sorry for these simple question i'm a PHP man.